# Build a gatsbyjs site from an azure dev ops pipeline

Tags: gulp, azure-devops, gatsby

I'm trying to build a gatsby static website from an Azure Dev ops build definition.

AzureDev ops provides a gulp task so I'm trying to create a simple gulpfile to wrap the build process of gatsby.

Right now I tried :

```
const gatbsyCli = require('gatsby-cli/lib/create-cli');

function gatsbyBuild() {
    gatbsyCli([ 'build' ]);
}

exports.gatsbyBuild = gatsbyBuild;
```

However, the task only show the command line help:

```
Usage: gulp.js <command> [options]

Commands:
  gulp.js develop                   Start development server. Watches files, rebuilds, and hot reloads if something
                                    changes
  gulp.js build                     Build a Gatsby project.
  gulp.js serve                     Serve previously built Gatsby site.
  gulp.js info                      Get environment information for debugging and issue reporting
  gulp.js repl                      Get a node repl with context of Gatsby environment, see (add docs link here)
  gulp.js new [rootPath] [starter]  Create new Gatsby project.

Options:
  --verbose      Turn on verbose output                                                       [boolean] [default: false]
  --no-color     Turn off the color in output                                                 [boolean] [default: false]
  -h, --help     Show help                                                                                     [boolean]
  -v, --version  Show version number                                                                           [boolean]

Pass --help to see all available commands and options.
[22:28:15] The following tasks did not complete: gatsbyBuild
[22:28:15] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

How to build a gatsby site from gulp ?

Is there any better way to reach my goal ?

**[Edit]** Also tried:

```
const gatbsyBuildImpl = require('gatsby/dist/commands/build.js');

function gatsbyBuild() {
    gatbsyBuildImpl();
}

exports.gatsbyBuild = gatsbyBuild;
```

but fails with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'openTracingConfigFile' of undefined`

**[/Edit]**

**[Edit 2019-02-02]** Regarding answers, here's update regarding my progress.

First, I try to use NPM action to build the site, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54303620/588868).

However, it fails with the following error:

```
2019-02-02T21:13:22.3306376Z [command]/usr/local/bin/npm run build
2019-02-02T21:13:27.6097839Z error GraphQL Error There was an error while compiling your site's GraphQL queries.
2019-02-02T21:13:27.6098171Z 
2019-02-02T21:13:27.6099612Z   Error: RelayParser: Encountered duplicate defintitions for one or more documents: each document must have a unique name. Duplicated documents:
2019-02-02T21:13:27.6100019Z > gatsby-starter-blog@1.0.0 build /home/vsts/work/1/s
2019-02-02T21:13:27.6100847Z - DefaultSEOQuery
2019-02-02T21:13:27.6100902Z > gatsby build
```

However, I don't understand this error. The site perfectly builds locally.

My gatbsy-node.js query is :

```
            `
{
  allMarkdownRemark(sort: {fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC}, limit: 1000) {
    edges {
      node {
        fields {
          slug
        }
        frontmatter {
          title
        }
      }
    }
    cats: group(field: frontmatter___categories, limit:1000) {
      fieldValue
      totalCount
    }
    tags: group(field: frontmatter___tags, limit:1000) {
      fieldValue
      totalCount
    }
  }
}
```

Also, here's my yaml definition :

```
resources:  
- repo: self    
queue:    
  name: Hosted Ubuntu 1604    
  demands: npm

steps:    
- task: Npm@1    
  displayName: 'npm install'    
  inputs:    
    verbose: false       

- task: Npm@1    
  displayName: 'npm custom'    
  inputs:    
    command: custom        
    verbose: false  
    customCommand: 'run build'
```

Moving to "Hosted" agent, throw another error:

```
019-02-02T21:52:17.2419822Z [0m
2019-02-02T21:52:17.2419867Z [0m  [0m[97m[41mError[0m[37m[41m:[0m[37m[41m [0m[97m[41m0-0cf4e58448448331aa6c.js from Terser[0m
2019-02-02T21:52:17.2421623Z [0m  [0m[97m[41mTypeError: Cannot read property 'minify' of undefined[0m
2019-02-02T21:52:17.2421678Z [0m  [0m[97m[41m    at minify (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:175:[0m  [0m[97m[41m22)[0m
2019-02-02T21:52:17.2421746Z [0m  [0m[97m[41m    at TaskRunner.boundWorkers.error [as boundWorkers] (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\[0m  [0m[97m[41mterser-webpack-plugin\dist\TaskRunner.js:68:40)[0m
2019-02-02T21:52:17.2421794Z [0m  [0m[97m[41m    at enqueue (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\TaskRunner.js[0m  [0m[97m[41m:89:14)[0m
2019-02-02T21:52:17.2421841Z [0m  [0m[97m[41m    at tryCatcher (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)[0m
2019-02-02T21:52:17.2421906Z [0m  [0m[97m[41m    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\bluebird\js\re[0m  [0m[97m[41mlease\promise.js:512:31)[0m
2019-02-02T21:52:17.2421954Z [0m  [0m[97m[41m    at Promise._settlePromise (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promi[0m  [0m[97m[41mse.js:569:18)[0m
2019-02-02T21:52:17.2422390Z [0m  [0m[97m[41m    at Promise._settlePromise0 (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\prom[0m  [0m[97m[41mise.js:614:10)[0m
2019-02-02T21:52:17.2422463Z [0m  [0m[97m[41m    at Promise._settlePromises (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\prom[0m  [0m[97m[41mise.js:690:18)[0m
2019-02-02T21:52:17.2422512Z [0m  [0m[97m[41m    at _drainQueueStep (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138[0m  [0m[97m[41m:12)[0m
2019-02-02T21:52:17.2422560Z [0m  [0m[97m[41m    at _drainQueue (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:131:9)[0m
2019-02-02T21:52:17.2422626Z [0m  [0m[97m[41m    at Async._drainQueues (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:[0m  [0m[97m[41m147:5)[0m
2019-02-02T21:52:17.2422677Z [0m  [0m[97m[41m    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\[0m  [0m[97m[41masync.js:17:14)[0m
2019-02-02T21:52:17.2422769Z [0m  [0m[97m[41m    at runCallback (timers.js:637:20)[0m
2019-02-02T21:52:17.2422832Z [0m  [0m[97m[41m    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:610:5)[0m
2019-02-02T21:52:17.2422878Z [0m  [0m[97m[41m    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:582:5)[0m

npm ERR! Failed at the gatsby-starter-blog@1.0.0 build script 'gatsby build'.
2019-02-02T21:52:17.2430701Z npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2019-02-02T21:52:17.2430849Z npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the gatsby-starter-blog package,
2019-02-02T21:52:17.2431116Z npm ERR! not with npm itself.
```

Comment: Can you provide your build yaml?

Comment: I don't have a yml file. I use the GUI in the portal to build my pipeline. Actually, I tried to create a yml file but didn't find a good quickstart

Comment: You can export the visual designer data to yaml - if you click "Edit" on the pipeline, there should be a "View YAML" button at the top right of the designer (when you have the "Pipeline" options selected on the left, which should be the default).

Comment: @EdwardThomson: thanks for the tips. This export is a good starting point to understand how yaml works. I've edited the question to add this file content.

Comment: 1. When gatsby develop is running fine on your local machine please try: to run "gatsby build" on your local machine.
2. Try it with a gatsby starter without changes from your side

Comment: @rubeonline: gatsby build works fine locally. Regarding using a non modified starter, I can actually build the starter blog using the same configuration than my project. There's probably something wrong within my project, not with azure build pipeline. Your answer below is the answer to the original question. I'll dive a bit more to isolate my issue. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use npm. Two build steps are enough for the first start:

1. Install dependencies

   `npm install`
2. build

   `npm run build`

Before you can do that your **package.json** need the following script (which is in every gatsbyJS Boilerplate available):

[image]

Comment: I can see the build is actually triggered, however, it fails with a cryptic error. I put this error in the question.

Comment: As suggested, I tried with a non modified starter. In this case, it works as expected.